# Prefix name of functions with “Try”

Tags: java

I read in the book "Clean Code" from Robert C. Martin (at page 71) that the better way to handle try/catch block is to separate process (the "try" part) from the error handling (the "catch part"). Each part should have a dedicated function

Example from the book, illustrating a better way to handle try/catch :

```
public void delete(Page page) {
    try {
        deletePageAndAllReferences(page);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logError(e);
    }
}

private void deletePageAndAllReferences(Page page) throws Exception {
    deletePage(page);
    registry.deleteReference(page.name);
    configKeys.deleteKey(page.name.makeKey());
}

private void logError(Exception e) {
    logger.log(e.getMessage());
}
```

I'm totally agree with this advice. However, I'm wondering about the name of the function "delete". IMHO, this name is not enough explicit about what the function is doing (what is it deleting ?). Furthermore, I think that it also hides the fact that any exception raised will be catch inside this function and I think adding a prefix to the function name will clarify it.

But I'm also wondering about giving too much informations that might add useless complexity and decreased readability. So I don't know whether rename it "tryDeletePageAndAllReferences" will be a better name or not.

And, in a more general context, is it better to prefix those kind of function (I mean with only try catch blocks) with "try" ?

Thanks for your advice and also your feedback.

Comment: It's often better to describe the function's behavior in its documentation rather than trying to cram it all into its identifier.

Comment: @ Birfl But having to describe it in documentation might hide the fact that the function is not enough self-explicit IMHO

Answer (score 4):

You should look from the client point of view. Client does not care if you have try statement inside your function or not, it's an implementation detail.

"Try*" prefix I have seen used when convention is not to throw exception in case of error, but return false, or some other value to indicate the error.

So, to sum up:

- if you deal with exception inside the function, and task is done regardless of were there exception or not, there is no need for the "Try" prefix.
- if you mean to return the error value (`false` or whatever) then it is appropriate to name function as "Try*"
- Actually, I'd recommend you to ask yourself: **do you actually need to catch the exception there in that function**, maybe you need to pass it out to the next level, or wrap it in another exception? Then I think the prefix is not needed.

Comment: You never *need* to catch an exception as there’s always the option to vomit your error all over the user’s screen. That’s the wrong thing to ask. If you *can* catch it in a meaningful way, then do so. Aside from that, this answer offers good advice.

Comment: I'd say it should come from requirements, and in most cases one big catch on the very top is pretty reasonable starting point, which would stay so for most exceptions anyway.

Comment: Especially when there is a choice between reporting error through return value, or passing or wrapping the exception, then first option should be chosen very carefully.

Comment: That's where I disagree. I'd say exceptions should be considered very carefully as exceptions should be exceptional; not the default. Only use an exception if there's no easy way of reporting the problem via a return value, or if the error is serious.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the name now hides part of what the function is doing and that makes it result in seemingly not the best of examples. It's not just deleting the page, but also the references to it. But now you have to look at the context. Is deleting the references an implementation detail of this class? These references seem like an internal state, so it would simply be updating its internal state whenever a page is deleted and that's not something the client should have to worry about when deleting a page.

The client not knowing about the exception being caught should not be a problem either, assuming that is a logical thing for the function to do. Apparently, the program is not in an 'exceptional state' when the deleting of the page failed and all we have to do in response to it is log the event.

The other problem with prefixing such functions with 'try' is that you are communicating the function *is allowed to fail*. I wouldn't see an exception as being allowed to fail, as it should be an 'exceptional situation'. You can also see this in places like the .NET framework where functions prefixed with try return a boolean that indicates whether the operation has succeeded or not.